# How can I loop through Django management command *args?

Tags: python, django, command, args

I have the following code:

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Build static site output.'

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument('args')

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        """Request pages and build output."""
        if args:
            pages = args
            available = list(get_pages())
            invalid = []
            for page in pages:
                if page not in available:
                    invalid.append(page)
            if invalid:
                msg = 'Invalid pages: {}'.format(', '.join(invalid))
                raise CommandError(msg)
        else:
            ...
```

However when I run this command:

```
python prototypes.py build index
```

the command loops through each letter of the word `index`.

```
CommandError: Invalid pages: i, n, d, e, x
```

I want it to detect `index` as one argument and if I provide more arguments with spaces in between it should be looping through those.

If I don't add the `add_arguments` method it shows `unrecognized argument` in the console.

Comment: Django command use the standard [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) module (the parser you get is a subclass of `ArgumentParser`). The documentation is pretty extensive and has couple of example. It's a shame Django's documentation does not link to that of the argparse module.

Answer (score 1):

This method fixed my problem.

```
def add_arguments(self, parser):
    parser.add_argument('args', nargs='+')
```